# Как разделить список по словам?

Tags: python, json, list

У меня есть список, полученный из json файла, который мне нужно разделить по словам.
Код такой:

```
df1 = matrix[['product/title']]
df2 = df1.apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.astype(str)), axis=1) 
df_clean = pd.DataFrame({'clean': df2}) 
sent = [row.split(',') for row in df_clean['clean']]
sent[:10]
```

Аутпут кода получается таким:

```
 ['Crazy Shape Scissor Set'],
 ['Fiskars Softouch Multi-Purpose Scissors 10"'],
 ['Fiskars Softouch Multi-Purpose Scissors 10"'],
 ['Fiskars Softouch Multi-Purpose Scissors 10"'],
 ['Fiskars Softouch Multi-Purpose Scissors 10"'],
 ['Fiskars Softouch Multi-Purpose Scissors 10"'],
 ['Dritz(R) Extra Large Safety Pins-Size 3 65/Pkg'],
 ['Dritz(R) Extra Large Safety Pins-Size 3 65/Pkg'],
 ['Dritz(R) Extra Large Safety Pins-Size 3 65/Pkg']]
```

Для моей задачи нужно удалить все повторяющиеся элементы списка и сделать большой список из подсписков.
Использую такой код:

```
new = []

for x in sent:
    if x not in new:
        new.append(x)
new1 = []
for i in new:
    for j in i:
        [j.split(' ', 1)[0] for i in new]
        for m in j:
            new_list = [m for j in i for m in j]
            print(new_list)
```

Но он не соединяет подсписки, а делит их по буквам:

```
new = []

for x in sent:
    if x not in new:
        new.append(x)
new1 = []
for i in new:
    for j in i:
        [j.split(' ', 1)[0] for i in new]
        for m in j:
            #final_str = functools.reduce(lambda a,b : a + b, m)
            #final = tuple(m)
            new_list = [m for j in i for m in j]
            print(new_list)
#Отлично, но очень много повторов. Может повлиять на данные.
new = []
​
for x in sent:
    if x not in new:
        new.append(x)
new1 = []
for i in new:
    for j in i:
        [j.split(' ', 1)[0] for i in new]
        for m in j:
            #final_str = functools.reduce(lambda a,b : a + b, m)
            #final = tuple(m)
            new_list = [m for j in i for m in j]
            print(new_list)
```

Аутпут:

```
['C', 'r', 'a', 'z', 'y', ' ', 'S', 'h', 'a', 'p', 'e', ' ', 'S', 'c', 'i', 's', 's', 'o', 'r', ' ', 'S', 'e', 't']
['C', 'r', 'a', 'z', 'y', ' ', 'S', 'h', 'a', 'p', 'e', ' ', 'S', 'c', 'i', 's', 's', 'o', 'r', ' ', 'S', 'e', 't']
['C', 'r', 'a', 'z', 'y', ' ', 'S', 'h', 'a', 'p', 'e', ' ', 'S', 'c', 'i', 's', 's', 'o', 'r', ' ', 'S', 'e', 't']
['C', 'r', 'a', 'z', 'y', ' ', 'S', 'h', 'a', 'p', 'e', ' ', 'S', 'c', 'i', 's', 's', 'o', 'r', ' ', 'S', 'e', 't']
['C', 'r', 'a', 'z', 'y', ' ', 'S', 'h', 'a', 'p', 'e', ' ', 'S', 'c', 'i', 's', 's', 'o', 'r', ' ', 'S', 'e', 't']
['C', 'r', 'a', 'z', 'y', ' ', 'S', 'h', 'a', 'p', 'e', ' ', 'S', 'c', 'i', 's', 's', 'o', 'r', ' ', 'S', 'e', 't']
['C', 'r', 'a', 'z', 'y', ' ', 'S', 'h', 'a', 'p', 'e', ' ', 'S', 'c', 'i', 's', 's', 'o', 'r', ' ', 'S', 'e', 't']
['C', 'r', 'a', 'z', 'y', ' ', 'S', 'h', 'a', 'p', 'e', ' ', 'S', 'c', 'i', 's', 's', 'o', 'r', ' ', 'S', 'e', 't']
['C', 'r', 'a', 'z', 'y', ' ', 'S', 'h', 'a', 'p', 'e', ' ', 'S', 'c', 'i', 's', 's', 'o', 'r', ' ', 'S', 'e', 't']
['C', 'r', 'a', 'z', 'y', ' ', 'S', 'h', 'a', 'p', 'e', ' ', 'S', 'c', 'i', 's', 's', 'o', 'r', ' ', 'S', 'e', 't']
['C', 'r', 'a', 'z', 'y', ' ', 'S', 'h', 'a', 'p', 'e', ' ', 'S', 'c', 'i', 's', 's', 'o', 'r', ' ', 'S', 'e', 't']
```

Что я могу сделать, чтобы объединить подсписки в один, не теряя при этом слова?

Comment: Покажите лучше исходный список и ожидаемый результат. Уверен, что есть нанмого лучший способ как написать код для этого.

Comment: В Аутпут кода, который у вас получается, каждый список - это не список, а список, который состоит из одного элемента, длинной строки со словами через пробел. При переборе эта строка разделяется на буквы.

Comment: приведите пример того, что вы ожидаете получить на выходе.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял:

```
new_sent = [string.split() for string in set(lst[0] for lst in sent)]
```